# what is the unit of "focal length = 1.0" in findEssentialMat (openCV)?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

Recently I tried to calculate essential matrix by `findEssentialMat` function in openCV (
https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga13f7e34de8fa516a686a56af1196247f)
I noticed that the parameter `focal length=1.0` and `pp=(0,0)` by default, but what is the unit of these two values, m/mm/pixels?

Furthermore, shouldn't the principal point at the image center, i.e. (h/2,w/2) in pixel coordinates or (0.5,0.5) in normalized coordinates?

Comment: afaik, the camera intrinsics are typically measured in "pixels". You can convert to real metric distance if you know the size of your sensor. There is another opencv function to convert with known sensor size.

Comment: So what does `focal length = 1.0` mean? I think 1-pixel focal length is not reasonable either.

Comment: neither does principal point `pp = Point2d(0, 0),`. Sorry, I think you will have to have a look at the source code if default values are undocumented. But probably you can set both values to the actual focal length and pp of your camera, which then probably is identical to a result from calibrateCamera, which gives focalLength/pp in pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Micka is already right in his comment. The camera model of OpenCV is e.g. illustrated [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html). As you can see the image coordinate system is defined such that the x-axis points to the right and the y-axis points down. The origin is at the image center (where the optical axis z intersects the image plane) and that is why the default value for the **principal point** is `(0px,0px)`. This is a standard coordinate system definition in Computer Vision and e.g. Matlab uses the same.

The **focal length** is set to `1.0 px` because if your camera is not calibrated you can still calculate e.g. the Essential Matrix and the math gets easier.

If you want to use your camera matrix for a 3D reconstruction you should definitely calibrate your camera or insert appropriate values for focal length (and principal point). Theoretically, you can convert the pixel system to a metric system if you know the sensor size.